# My first Hello World Program isn't operating

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
a = 1;

int main()

{

    while ( a = 1 );
    {
        printf("10");
    }
}
```

I think i did everything correctly. Please correct my mistake. :)

Comment: We're not telepaths. Please elaborate on "isn't operating".

Comment: there isnt any form of output in terminal. its just blank

Comment: How do you run the program?

Comment: school software. allylocal @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Shouldn't it output errors if something's wrong? This code doesn't compile as is, and if you were using a half-decent compiler/IDE, you would get proper error messages. I suggest installing one, and using that school software only to upload the final results.

Comment: This isn't a "Hello World" program. Aside from that, I'd suggest going through a good C tutorial

Comment: OK. Sorry for disturbing you guys. :')

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon after `while` statement. That is stopping your code from executing there.

```
while ( a = 1 )
{
    printf("10");
}
```

Also, the argument to your while statement may not be what you are wanting to do. `while(a=1)` means a will always be equal to 1 and your while statement will continue forever. What you are probably wanting, instead, is `while(a==1)` which means "while a is equal to 1".

Comment: I thought need ; after every line in C?

Comment: @SOFTwARE Not true. That is used to signify the end of a statement.

Comment: ooh. cause that while function isnt end ah thats why no need ; ?

Comment: @SOFTwARE You are correct.

Comment: He also needs to change the = operator to ==.

Comment: @MrBens I agree, as others have pointed out, but one thing at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Your while statement is incorrect for its intent:

```
while ( a = 1 );
```

1. You use a semicolon `;` after the condition´s body. Although it is syntactically correct to do so, it will cause something different -> the `while` loop´s body will be treated as a separate block and your `while` will only constantly proof the condition.
2. You also use the wrong operator `=` instead of `==` for the check as `==` is required to be used in condition testings for comparison, not `0`. Else it would be actually assign `1` to `a` and the condition will always evaluate to be `true`.

The correct version is:

```
while ( a == 1 )
{
   ....
}
```

You also can combine the assignment to `a` with its definition:

```
int a = 10;
```

---

The corrected program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 1;

int main(void)
{
    while ( a == 1 )
    {
        printf("10");
    }
}
```

---

Note, that this program will **never terminate** and stopping to print `10`, because `a` never get changed. High-probably this will cause a run-time error.

---

Side note:

This isn´t a "Hello World"-program. This is a "Hello World" program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so for special things like while and elif, dont need ; after its end ah?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I'm new to C. It was easier in python. but then in C its harder cause have more strict syntex

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Not necessarily an error. OP's code would compile even with the `;`, but it wouldn't do the right thing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, yes, you´re right. Nonetheless, the `while` loop will never finish and thus the algorithm is obsolete.

Comment: @SOFTwARE It´s right that you can use a semicolon after the `while` condition  at some particular cases, where the condition has some sort of beneficial side effect, but that is not suitable to your example. So, it was wrong from me to say it would be a syntax error (I forgot this use case) - in fact, the compiler won´t throw a warning. But if you incorporate a body for the `while` statement (which shall be true for 98% of all use cases), it definitely should not have a semicolon as the execution would then work differently. I edited my answer accordingly, too.

Answer (score -1):

There is an extra semi colon after your while loop statement. You can remove that. The assigning you have with a = 1 should be a==1 which will compote instead of assign. I’m curious about your while condition though. How many times do you want “10” to print?

Comment: its just a test program. i just started learning c today thats why i wanted to like play around and find any mistake that i made. @Wisdom Writer

Comment: No absolutely, it’s just “a” is always going to be equivalent to 1 so there isn’t a terminating condition for you while loop. Increment after your while loop so it doesn’t run infinitely

Answer (score -1):

Remove the extra ; after while loop also you are using assignment operator in place of comparison operator

```
while(a==1)
{
  printf ("10");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To compare a value with variable '==' is used like 'a==1' so loop will look like this.
And make sure to add 'return 0' before last closing bracket.
also remove semicolon after while loop round bracket.

```
int a=1;

int main()
{
    while(a==1) {
     printf("10");
}
return 0;
}
```

You can use 'void main()' instead of 'int main()' to avoid returning a value.
To use 'void main()' replace it with 'int main()' and remove 'return 0'

Comment: `void main()` isn't permitted by the standard (even though some compilers support it). `return 0;` is unnecessary, it happens automatically in `main` (at least since C99).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but using int main() you have to return a value right? so return 0 is needed

Comment: In any other function yes, but `main` is an exception. See explanation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).